# Access jwtFromRequest from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-jwt

I'm learning **passport.js** with `JWT` strategy and I want to create a system to logout users.

I want to process like that:

1. When a user logs out, his token is stored in my database, in a table called `InvalidTokens`
2. Each time a user makes a protected request, I want to check if his token is  in the table `InvalidTokens` or not

The thing is that I don't know how to access the field `jwtFromRequest` in the code below:

```js
// passport.js
// File where I store my authentication strategies

// ...

/**
 * Use JWT strategy for all the other requests that need authentication on the
 * server 
 */
var opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: 'secret',
}

passport.use('jwt', new JWTStrategy(
  opts,
  async (jwtPayload, done) => {
    try {
      const token = await TokenInvalide.findOne({
        where: {
          Token: '<token_value_I_can\'t_reach>',
        }
      })

      if (token !== null)
        return done(null, false);

      return done(null, jwtPayload.idUtilisateur);

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return done(null, false);
    }
  }
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the doc](https://github.com/mikenicholson/passport-jwt) you can pass the `request` object to the call back by setting the `passReqToCallback` to true

Haven't tested this but should be the right direction

```
var opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: 'secret',

  passReqToCallback: true // <----- Add this

}

passport.use('jwt', new JWTStrategy(
  opts,
  async (req, jwtPayload, done) => {

    const rawJWTToken = req['Authorization'].split(' ')[1]

    ...
  }
));
```